# Exiftool doesn't return some data when run in AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, exiftool

Running ExifTool(10.68) locally on a **.mpg** or a **.mpeg** returns the field `Composite:Duration`. ExifTool itself is called from python code as a subprocess with switches `-j -G -n`. When this python runs as a lambda function on AWS, the `Composite:Duration` just isn't there. `FileSize` is also missing on AWS.

With other formats like **.avi** it works both locally and on AWS.

Tried using other parameters for exiftool, `-a -U -q`, without any success.

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen([self.EXIFTOOL, '-j', '-G', '-n', '-'],
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

To sum up I expect the same data is returned on AWS as on local